# Will spark.akka.frameSize still work in spark 2.x?

Tags: apache-spark

As we know that the spark.akka.frameSize will work when the underlying communication framework is akka when spark version <= 1.6.0  ;

My Question is when spark version is 2.x akka is reaplaced by netty , will this parameter still work ? Or are there any similiar parameters for netty which works the same as spark.akka.frameSize for akka ? Thank you for any suggestions !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can tune the `spark.rpc.message.maxSize` config parameter. This is documented [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#networking)